# How to properly validate 2 or more fields together in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate 2 fields together using JavaScript code.
What i'm doing is disabling the submit button when user enters invalid data.

Something like this:

[Disabled Button when incorrect data is entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iQhM.jpg)

The problem is that when i enter invalid data in field 1 the button is disabled but when i add proper form data in second field the button gets enabled again, i even used global variable but the problem still persists.

[Button enabled even if data in first field is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2DJx.jpg)

My JavaScript code is :

```
<script>
var sw=0;
function valqid(qid){

 if(isNaN(qid) || parseInt(qid)<0){
  alert("Please Enter Valid Question ID!");
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  window.sw=1; 
 }
 else{
  if(window.sw==0){
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
 }
 }


}

function valans(ans){

 if(parseInt(ans)!=0 && parseInt(ans)!=1){
  alert("Please Enter Valid Answer!");
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  window.sw=1; 
 }
 else{
  if(window.sw==0){
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
 }
 }


}
</script>
```

Here qid and ans are values inputted by user.

Kindly tell me how to make it work properly.
(Validation rules are listed below in image files)

Thanks in advance.

Complete Code HTML is given below:

```
<html>
 <body> 
  <center> 
   <form action="add_questions.php" method="POST" name="form4"> <br /> <br />
    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="1">
     <tr> <th> Question ID </th> <th> Question </th> <th> Answer </th> </tr>
     <tr> <td> <input type="text" name="question_id" maxlength="3" minlength="1" onchange="valqid(this.value)" required /> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="question" maxlength="200" minlength="10" id="ques" required /> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="answer" maxlength="1" onchange="valans(this.value)" required /> </td> </tr>
    </table> <br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Question" name="add_question" id="button" />
   </form> <br /> <br />
  <p> * Enter Question Id, Question & Answer of the question you want to add. </p>
  <p> * All three are mandatory fields (cannot be empty). </p>
  <p> * Question Id can be 3 numbers (Whole Numbers only) long at most and should be atleast 1 number (character).</p>
  <p> * Question can be 200 characters long at most and should be atleast 10 characters. </p>
  <p> * Answer field should be '1' for 'True' & '0' for 'False'.</p>
  <p> * Question Id must be unique.</p>

<script>
var sw=0;
function valqid(qid){

 if(isNaN(qid) || parseInt(qid)<0){
  alert("Please Enter Valid Question ID!");
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  window.sw=1; 
 }
 else{
  if(window.sw==0){
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
 }
 }


}

function valans(ans){

 if(parseInt(ans)!=0 && parseInt(ans)!=1){
  alert("Please Enter Valid Answer!");
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  window.sw=1; 
 }
 else{
  if(window.sw==0){
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
 }
 }


}
</script>




 </body>
</html> ;
```

Comment: Why did you make 2 functions instead of 1?

Comment: Because the input value to function is coming when user is inputting a value.

Comment: I can upload the whole html file if you want?

Comment: Assuming the form can contain both of the values at the same time, you pass them into a single function and check if either of them are null (and disable the button), and then check if there values are valid. Something like: `if(x == null || y == null) { disableButton(); } else if(isValid(x) && isValid(y)) { enableButton(); } else { disableButton(); }`

Comment: Let me upload the whole code please.

Comment: Can you now please suggest the changes in my whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple way

```
<script>
function valqid(qid){
 if(isNaN(qid) || parseInt(qid)<0){
  alert("Please Enter Valid Question ID!");
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
 }
 else if(parseInt(ans)!=0 && parseInt(ans)!=1){
  alert("Please Enter Valid Answer!");
  document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  }
 else{
     document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: But the ans variable will not have any value unless valans function is called.

Comment: In that case you should simply call valqid(); at the end of you 2nd method, It will check the status for the first method, whether the first method has made the button enable or disable

Comment: Can you now please suggest the changes in my whole code.